# Why moblie device access web pages slower than PC?

Tags: frontend, iphone-web-app

I have a question about a iphone and PC,connecting same WiFi,open same webpage,PC less than 1s but iphone need 3-5s. Recenty i developing a webapp and in view of this situation how to optimize webapp.

Comment: how do you mean? Keeping it as small as possible seems an obvious answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Slower network access (small bandwidth + hight latency).

+ Slower CPU

_____________

= slower web rendering
```

Solutions ?

1 ) Minimize the connections (objects number of your page).

2 ) Minimize the total size.

3 ) Minimize client-side computations (rarely needed except for complex web apps).

The latency problem is important. Consider using sprites to regroup images. And of course don't use big images when small ones are enough.

As mobile devices are more and more diverse, it's better not to try to focus on detection and specific optimization, but apply general web site optimization (Google here would be your friend).

Answer (score 0):

First, probably because iPhone and PC hasn't same perfs.

Even if it's the same webpage, the render motor isn't the same.

Optimise your webpage using a css focused on mobile devices is a good start :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of factors affecting performance:

cpu processing speed/power: your PC probably has a better cpu. This means it can execute more instructions quicker.

web browser: The specific web browsers might be slower/faster at rendering the page. The browsers are probably using different javascript engines and that will also effect performance.

memory: the amount and speed of memory between the 2 systems will effect performance.

ect....